# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError 1044 Access denied for user using Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I was trying to access the mysql databases from server A to server "apple" using the Python Django. The relevant statements are

```
import settings
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = runconfig.django_settings_module
from django.db import connection

class Writer(object):
  def __init__(self):

  def submission(self,pars):
    d = connection.cursor()
```

and running this gives me the error as below:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'username'@'ice.cse.connell.edu' to database 'mydatabase'")
```

The content of runconfig.py is

```
# Django setting module 
django_settings_module = 'settings'
```

Strangely, I am able to login to mysql from server "ice" to server "apple" remotely:

```
$ mysql -u username -ppassword -h apple
```

I have been digging this problem from SO but still cannot find an answer. This question has been driven me crazy!

Below is the first few lines of my settings.py. Because it is too long, I did not post all of it. But if any one needs more, I can paste all the content.

```
# Django settings for mydatabase project.

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'          # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = 'mydatabase'  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = 'username'             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'password'         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = 'apple'            # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**APPENDED POST**

After modifying the settings.py based on Sid's suggestion:

```
#DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'           
#DATABASE_NAME = 'mydatabase'   
#DATABASE_USER = 'username'             
#DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'password'         
#DATABASE_HOST = 'apple'  
#DATABASE_PORT = ''     

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'apple',
    'PORT': '',
  }
}
```

The command line inputs and error messages are

```
>>> import runconfig
>>> 
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> import settings
>>> #from django.conf import settings
... 
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = runconfig.django_settings_module
>>> 
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> c = connection.cursor()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured, "You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE setting yet."
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE setting yet.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your database name, it may be case-sensitive.

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/8717661c908b836e

Try Using the following format:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'mydatabase', 
        'USER': 'username',     
        'PASSWORD': 'password', 
        'HOST': 'apple',
        'PORT': '',     
    }
 }
```

Also, does the username you are using have privileges to this database?

Comment: I checked settings.py and the database name is correct. It is always lower cased in my case.

Comment: @fanchyna mind posting your settings.py database config? What driver are you using? pyodbc?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I have edit my original post and appended the first few lines of settings.py since it is too long. If you need all content let me know. By the way, will the ROOT_URLCONF value matters? I guess not, as I am just trying to connect to the remote database other than feeding data for a server but welcome to any questions.

Comment: I have edit the settings.py based on your answer, but this time, it throws an "Improperly Configured" error. I have "copy" and "pasted" the new settings.py and error messages to my original post.

Comment: @fanchyna I'm not sure why this is happening. Does the database exist? does the username have permissions to it? can you try logging in with a user that has root permissions and see if that works?

Comment: I have one question, why do I need to use "settings.py" twice? I mean I first "import settings" in the command line, but I also set the "django_settings_module" to 'settings'. I doubt if the latter one is using the updated "settings.py" but I am not sure. I am new to the Django. Sorry for my bad questions.

Comment: @fanchyna What do you mean in the cmd line?

Comment: @fanchyna but does the username you are using have privileges to this database?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by "cmd" line, I mean after I started "python2.6", I can input each command manually. So I can input commands like "import settings"; "from django.db import connection"; and "c = connecton.cursor()". This is used to test if I can establish a connection. If this works, the program should work. Hope this clarifies the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: The issue was resolved and solved. It is because I did not grant the right permission to 'username', which is why although I can access mysql remotely but I cannot see the database I wanted to see. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8140/discussion-between-fanchyna-and-sid)